# How do I change the background color of a resizable handle of a JQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, css

You'd think it would be easy, but keep reading.  I can change many of the styles associated with a resizable JQuery Dialog, but not the handles.  The code below isolates the problem.  Why does the handle disappear entirely?   There must be some logic I'm interfering with in ui.resizable.js, but I don't see it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="jquery126.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="ui/ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="ui/ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="ui/ui.resizable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="ui/ui.draggable.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(foo);
  function foo() {
    $("#dlg").dialog()
  }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  .ui-resizable-n {
    background: green;
  }
</style>
<div id=dlg title="my title">this is<br>my text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work.  I couldn't find the line of code my css was in conflict with, but when I added positioning and size related css, things worked.  There must be some logic that says, "use the default css unless the programmer has supplied his own".   So, while I thought I was appending info, I was somehow swapping info.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the background of the resizeable borders are set as images, which in CSS stacking is on top of backgrounds.  Try setting:

```
.ui-resizable-n{
  background-image:none;
  background-color:green;
}
```